# Error on connecting to python libraries

Tags: python, qt, dll, pyqt

I have a project that has code which will communicate with a python script and call python functions. In the proj file, i've added the includePath for the python header files, and added external python library to the project (python27.a). However the qt compiler gave me an error:

> No rule to make target
>
> /home/pgeng/work/OpenModelica-rev.9876.CSA/OMEdit/OMEditGUI/../../../../../../usr/lib/python2.7/libpython2.a
>
> , needed by `../bin/OMEdit`. Stop

What does this mean? How can i fix it? this is anything related to PyQt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `libpython2` is missing.

You will have to :

1. Find out what package provides this library.
2. You can Google for that.
3. Or search a repo for the lib.